# Powershell Construct Date ForEach Returns Date for First File Multiple Times

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put together a foreach loop that will give me the date in each of the file names constructed using substrings on the filename using the following code:

```
$DailyFile = gci '\\web-servr-w01\Accounting' | ? {$_.Name -like 'GL_XTRAK_*'} | select -First 5 |select -ExpandProperty Name

$FileMon = $DailyFile.Substring(24,2)
$FileDay = $DailyFile.Substring(26,2)
$FileYr = $DailyFile.Substring(28,4)

$FileDate = get-date -Year $FileYr -Month $FileMon -Day $FileDay -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"

foreach($File in $DailyFile)
{
$FileDate
}
```

But running that gives me the following output:

```
04-30-2019
04-30-2019
04-30-2019
04-30-2019
04-30-2019
```

When I was expecting:

```
04-30-2019
05-01-2019
05-02-2019
05-03-2019
05-04-2019
```

I've verified that the code works when I only select a single file by modifying the GCI statement using '-skip 1 -first 1' or -skip 2 -first 1' etc.

I'm a Powershell novice so please be gentle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over *all* the files and grab the date parameters from each of them:

```
$DailyFileNames = gci '\\web-servr-w01\Accounting' | ? {$_.Name -like 'GL_XTRAK_*'} | select -First 5 |select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach($FileName in $DailyFileNames)
{
    $FileMon = $FileName.Substring(24,2)
    $FileDay = $FileName.Substring(26,2)
    $FileYr = $FileName.Substring(28,4)

    $FileDate = Get-Date -Year $FileYr -Month $FileMon -Day $FileDay -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"

    $FileDate
}
```

At which point you might notice that turning the strings into a `DateTime` object and back to a string again is unnecessary:

```
$DailyFileNames = gci '\\web-servr-w01\Accounting' | ? {$_.Name -like 'GL_XTRAK_*'} | select -First 5 |select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach($FileName in $DailyFileNames)
{
    $FileMon = $FileName.Substring(24,2)
    $FileDay = $FileName.Substring(26,2)
    $FileYr = $FileName.Substring(28,4)

    "$FileMon-$FileDay-$FileYr"
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I had tried putting the variables inside { }  but I didn't realize I had to change the variable $DailyFile to whatever's defined in Foreach (aka $FileName).